# FCM REST send message 401 unauthorised even when sending server key

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, authorization

Using Firebase FCM REST API I got 401 unauthorised error.
I actually do sending server key like the following:

[image]

What I am missing in here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the legacy API, works like a charm:

```
POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

{
    "to": DEVICE_TOKEN,
    "notification": {
        "title": "Hello World title",
        "body": "Notification content"
    },
    "data": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Using the same headers I provided in the question.